# AES Encrypt VB Function to PHP Function

Tags: php, vb.net

I have the following VB function that receives the following parameters:

input: 145145

pass: CeMdGrTeV6BtrEg0p8sUMg==

and return the string: KT8uZ9nlacOFBfg1nPY+zA==

I tried to turn the individual steps into php but I can not get the same output, someone knows how I can do?

```
    Public Function AES_Encrypt(ByVal input As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
    Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
    Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim encrypted As String = ""

    Try
      Dim hash(31) As Byte
      Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass))

      Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
      Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
      AES.Key = hash
      AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
      Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor
      Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)
      encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
      Return encrypted
    Catch ex As Exception
      Return ""
    End Try
  End Function
```

Comment: So show us what you tried please

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code conversion site

Comment: Maybe you should try it with sodium: https://bitbeans.gitbooks.io/libsodium-net/content/password_hashing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I have solved!

```
private function AES_Encrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
    $cipher = 'AES-256-ECB';
    $plaintext = $sValue;
    $key = $sSecretKey;
    $key = base64_encode(md5(mb_convert_encoding($key, "UCS-2LE", "JIS, eucjp-win, sjis-win"), true));

    $keyBytes = md5($key, true);

    for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($keyBytes, 'ASCII'); $i++) {
        $temp1[] = $keyBytes[$i];
    }

    $temp2 = $temp1;
    unset($temp1[count($temp1)-1]);

    $temp3 = array_merge($temp1,$temp2);

    $key = implode('',$temp3);

    $enc = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options = 0);

    return $enc;

}
```